# Not getting an action change dynamically

Tags: javascript, action

I have the following code

```
alert("Submit the form");
document.form[0].action = "contact_form3.asp?proc=true";
alert("action changed?");
document.form[0].submit();
```

For the life of me I cannot get it to change the action to the one shown aboove. It just continues to go to contact_form3.asp ans that's it.

The first alert occurs, but then it is submitted.

Help appreciated and let me know if you need to see more example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `document.forms[0]` (with *forms* in plural) instead of `document.form[0]`.